# Can not run EXCEL.EXE with "runas", it says: "1312: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, runas, windows-10-v2004

I need to run EXCEL.EXE with a user different than current one; previously I have been doing this without any issues using "runas", but after updating the system to Windows 10 Pro version 2004 (19041.508) this method is not working anymore.

This is what I am doing:

```
C:\Users\forla>runas /profile /user:probanduela "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE"
Escriba la contraseña para probanduela:
Intentando iniciar C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE como usuario "DESKTOP-PGDBNMB\probanduela" ...
ERROR RUNAS: no se puede ejecutar - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
1312: Una sesión de inicio especificada no existe. Es posible que haya finalizado.
```

I am getting all times the error (english version):

1312: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.

Similar issue happens if I try to run it through PowerShell or through win32 API, or through c# API.

This method was working before upgrading to Windows 10 2004 version, I've reproduced this on different computers.

What's the issue? How can I achieve what I want to do ?

-Edit-

Just discovered that using Excel v2002 build 12527.21104 it works; but with Excel v2008 build 13127.20408 it fails.

So apparently is a combination of Windows 10 v2004 + Office 2019 v2008 what causes the issue.

-Edit2-

If I make a copy of EXCEL.EXE and give it another name, like "EXCEL_COPY.EXE" it works. But still not work with WINWORD.EXE.

Comment: Seems like a new bug; not much is known about it yet.

Comment: @harrymc It's not a double post, at stackoverflow I ask on having the issue through c# code, here through system administration tool.. The sideeffect is same on both :(

Answer (score 0):

I reported that issue to Microsoft and, after raising up few levels, they have worked on it and fixed. It's fixed on [Windows 10 Build 19042.844](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2021/02/17/releasing-windows-10-build-19042-844-20h2-to-beta-and-release-preview-channels/)